# How do I store multiple values at one array index?

Tags: javascript

I've tried to do

```
'somethin' || 'something'
```

in an array, but when I did

```
let answers = ['object oriented programming' || 'oop', '2 + 2' || '2+2', 'bark', 'the stone table' || 'stone table', 'a bridge' || 'bridge', 'the riddle of the day!' || 'the riddle of the day' || 'riddle of the day!' || 'riddle of the day', 'food']

if (prompt(riddles[0]).toLowerCase() == answers[0]) {
    console.log('Yes!!!')
} else {
    console.log('Sorry, but no. :|')
}
```

the console said, "Sorry, but no. :|."

Am I supposed to do something with the `||` (the 'or' statement)?

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve? Do you want to check whether if input is present inside array?

Comment: You only show the answer array, what about the other array called riddles? And make sure you also put answer[0] to toLowerCase()

Comment: @MauricePheyton I did that... look **_again_**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a nested array to store multiple values:

```
let answers = [['object oriented programming', 'oop'], ['2 + 2', '2+2'], ['bark'], ['the stone table', 'stone table'], ['a bridge', 'bridge'], ['the riddle of the day!', 'the riddle of the day', 'riddle of the day!', 'riddle of the day'], ['food']];

if (answers[0].includes(prompt(riddles[0]).toLowerCase())) {
    console.log('Yes!!!')
} else {
    console.log('Sorry, but no. :|')
}
```

Comment: Thanks! :D But what does, "answers[0] _.includes_ " mean?

Comment: @UnknownBobby Since each element is now a collection of answers you can no longer use `prompt(riddles[0]).toLowerCase() == answers[0]`. A single answer never equals a collection of answers. For this reason you should use [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and check if the collection of correct answers includes the given answer.